# How to efficiently sample a matrix in matlab, given a list of coordinates with repeatitions

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a list of coordinates to a matrix, and I want to sample the matrix elements from it. The list of coordinates is with repetitions and actually is larger than the number of elements in the matrix.

e.g.

```
A = magic(3)

coords = [1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     3     1
     3     2
     3     3
     1     1
     1     2
     1     3
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     3     1
     3     2
     3     3];
```

I want to get back a vector of values (pseudo code): `sample_from_matrix(A, coords)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it that way:

```
A( sub2ind( size(A), coords(:,1), coords(:,2) ) )
```

If you want to remove coordinate duplicates first:

```
coords = unique( coords, 'rows' );
A( sub2ind( size(A), coords(:,1), coords(:,2) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, works *much* faster than my priliminary solution `arrayfun(@(k) A(coords(k, 1), coords(k, 2)), 1:size(coords,1))`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know if my solution was faster than yours. ;)